# How is sin() implemented in eglibc-2.13?

Tags: c, linux, math, glibc, libc

I need to track down how exactly is `double sin(double x)` implemented in eglibc-2.13. I downloaded the source code and the only part that made sense was __sin function, that was platform-specific. Is it the heart of what I have in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a?

How to track down the macrodefinitions that lead from sin() to __sin()? What I **really** need is the exact code (filename and the line is enough) and a way in which the build process deduces which implementation to use. The architecture's i386.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (e)glibc build process is black, black magic.  You do not want to try to comprehend it.  However, glibc adheres to a one-file-per-public-function coding style, so in general, if you have the source tree and you want to find the implementation(s) of some function, the easiest thing to do is

```
$ find * -name '*function*' -print
```

from the top level, replacing `function` with the name of the function, of course.

Talking specifically about `sin`: the generic implementations of the math functions are in the `math` directory: however, it appears that there *is* no generic definition of `sin`.  So the next place to look is `sysdeps`.  Everything that isn't generic is in `sysdeps`, and in particular, `sysdeps/ieee754` is where all the math functions that have some dependence on the IEEE 754 floating point specification, but no other system dependencies, live.  This directory is organized by type: `sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64` contains all the math functions for IEEE `double`.  And here you will find [`sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD), which is the code you are looking for.  (The `e_`, `s_`, `k_`, etc prefixes on all these files used to mean something but AFAIK no longer do.)

If there were an implementation of `sin` in assembly language for a particular processor, it would be in a file named `sin.S` (or possibly `s_sin.S`) somewhere else in `sysdeps`.  It does not appear that there is one, though.

Comment: Indeed, as far as I know there is no asm for `sin` because there's no direct way to write it in assembly short of just optimizing what the C code is already doing. The x87 fsin/fcos instructions are not sufficient for implementing an IEEE conformant `sin` function. And if you want a nonconformant speed hack, gcc `-ffast-math` will do that for you.

Comment: It's conceivable that someone could've written a hand-optimized assembly implementation taking advantage of SSE or what have you, but no one seems to have bothered, at least not for x86.

Comment: @R..: There is no barrier to writing directly `sin` in assembly without referring to C code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I didn't say there is. I just said that an assembly implementation would just be performing the same algorithm the current C code is performing, but hand-optimized rather than optimized by a compiler. By "direct", I meant something like the `fsqrt` instruction that does the entire job of `sqrt()`, or as a less trivial example, the way you can implement `exp` in 387 assembly using specialized exponential instructions.

Comment: @R..: there are a number of things that one might want to do in writing an implementation of `sin` or `cos` that are not necessarily easily representable in C.  Off the top of my head, on a 64-bit platform, one might use integer instructions for argument reduction and want to take advantage of the x86 64bx64b -> 128b multiply instruction; one might also do floating-point computations for reduction and want to take advantage of the SSE4.1 `roundsd` instruction to get a final rounding to integral with a static rounding mode.  I'm sure I can think of more examples.

Comment: Do you have in mind a way to do the argument reduction efficiently with integer math? Trigonometric argument reduction is pretty hard to get right, and I'm always interested in new approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but just a bit of a background:

When you use `sin()` or `cos()` in your C code, it is almost certainly the *compiler* that provides the implementation, rather than your C library. As an example, look at [the list of builtins GCC provides](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins). The linked page also describes the cases where the built-ins are used rather than the versions the C library provides.

Comment: But how? I'm linking against libm.a from libc6-dev:
`> locate libm.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a`


`> apt-file search /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a
libc6-dev: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a`

Comment: Nearly all those GCC builtins just make a few optimizations and then forward to the C library routine or a similar one.  For instance, if GCC knows that the C library has `sinf` available it may convert `float y = sin(x)` (where `x` is also `float`) to a call to `sinf`.  Adding a full C99 math library to GCC has been discussed but not so far implemented AFAIK.

Comment: @Zack, you're right. I didn't notice the linkage as I mostly use the vector extension built-ins for SSE2/3 instead, which do not call any functions but produce the actual operations directly. It really just didn't occur to me GCC does not bother to map these built-ins to the assembly instructions.. Well, another place to optimize tight computational simulation code on x86-64, I guess. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: I didn't know there were SSE trig instructions, I thought those went out with the old-fashioned x87 FPU instruction set.  In any case I would expect them to be too inaccurate even for `-ffast-math`.

Comment: No, there are just addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, square root, imprecise reciprocal square root, min, max, comparisons, binary operations, and moves and shuffling/swizzling. I haven't needed `sin()`, `cos()` in a long time in anything performance-critical; I was just extremely surprised they are external functions and not inlined.